# Storing ONE global value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store one global decimal value.

Would the best way to approach this be to store the value in a .txt file, or make an entire table for it in MySQL which will contain a single row for the value, or is there a different way?

Comment: How often does the value change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It deppends on how often you will access it and how performance critical your application is. In brief DataBase should be your default unless you have a strong reason not to.

The reasons to keep the data in the database it's because it makes everything simplier and neater, backups don't need to worry about random .txt files that may be overlooked (And this a incomplete backup). If you need to set up a cluster it's a real PITA to keep files real-time synched while most databases support it easily, etc.

**Why wouldn't you keep something in the database?**

- It's a enviroment value and thus in each installation of your
  software the value may be different while using the same DB (In this
  case people use File storage like the usual config .yml)
- It's really performance critical to
  have a top notch access-time to this data, for this people use
  specialized engines to store such data (Redis, memcached, etc)

Now, answering your question, how to store it in your own db, that's up to you, but I would think something like a table named "GlobalConfigurations" with a column key and value could be a good approach. So that if you find any other variable with the same behavior you can put it there.